# Python wand drawed polygons instead of rectangle when stroke_width > 2

Tags: python, wand

I'm not sure what I did wrong, but this is really strange.
Not sure whether I should submit a new issue to wand's Git repository.

edit: I am trying to draw a rectangle.

Consider the following code:

```
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image
def drawer():
    square = Drawing()
    square.fill_color = Color('#fff')
    square.stroke_width = 4
    square.stroke_color = Color('red')
    square.rectangle(left=100, top=100, width=100, height=100)
    return square

im = Image(width=500, height=500)
sq = drawer()
sq.draw(im)
im.save(filename='test1.png')
```

And this outputs:

[image: weird image 1]

From what I've tried-and-error'd, this won't happen if `square.stroke_width` is less or equal than 2.

I'm not sure whether it's Wand's bug or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: FYI I just tried this under Python 3.4.3 with wand 0.4.1 and your code works fine.

Comment: Just BTW here, but you might want to be more specific about the resulting output, because a rectangle is a kind of polygon. Actually, with the extra lines sticking out, I wouldn't even call that a polygon.

Comment: Tried on different `virtualenv` with python 3.4 or 2.7, both acts like this. Also tried on different machine.

Comment: What I am trying to draw is like what @emcconville did, but it's still not working with the code provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. The `libmagickwand-dev` on ubuntu's APT repository is outdated.

```
$ python -m wand.version -v
Wand 0.4.2
ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
$ apt-cache show  libmagickwand-dev | grep Version
Version: 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3
```

So I updated it. Following the instructions provided [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix) and I added

`export MAGICK_HOME=/usr/local/lib/` to my environment variable.
And it worked.

```
$ python -m wand.version -v
Wand 0.4.1
ImageMagick 6.9.2-0 Q16 x86_64 2015-09-08 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have orphaned drawing instances. Wand leverages python's `with ... as ... :` keyword(s) to manage context & resources. Example...

```py
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color
from wand.image import Image

class Drawer(Drawing):
    def __enter__(self):
        super(Drawing, self).__enter__()
        self.fill_color = Color('#fff')
        self.stroke_width = 4
        self.stroke_color = Color('red')
        self.rectangle(left=100, top=100, width=100, height=100)
        return self

with Image(width=500, height=500) as im:
    with Drawer() as sq:
        sq(im)
    im.save(filename='/tmp/test1.png')
```

[image: rectangel]

Comment: Still not working. What version are you using? I'm using Wand 0.4.1 and Python 3.4 :(

Comment: Looks like there's some kind of bug. I've raised an issue at the repository. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine according to http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/guide/draw.html . If you go to the bottom of the page it shows how to draw polygons. Compared to what your code looks like, it should work fine. I don't know what's wrong, but I'm pretty sure your code is OK.

Comment: If you're drawing a rectangle use the **rectangle()** method, it's on the page from the link in my answer. I just assumed because you used the same code required for a polygon :)